# Is there any type of lightsaber mace?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

My friend and I were joking around about Mace Windu having a mace instead of a lightsaber and that got me wondering: is there any type of mace that uses lightsaber technology?

Comment: Does Mace Windu count?

Comment: @Adamant - They already made that joke.

Comment: With all the lightsaber variations out there, I am waiting to see light nunchaku.

Comment: How would a "mace" be any different? Having a bit different shape of a blade?

Answer (score 9):

In a word, no. There are no variants of the lightsaber that meet your description of a 'light mace'. Probably the closest is a [lightclub](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightclub), which is basically a big fat lightsaber.

There are, however, 'resonator maces', 'vibro-maces' and 'riot control batons' that use other tech to create a heavy club that will also incapacitate anyone that it hits, but these don't generally have the sort of fine cutting effect that we associate with lightsaber technology.

[image]
[A resonator mace](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Resonator_mace).

[image]
[A vibro mace](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vibro_mace)

[image]
[A riot-control baton](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Z6_riot_control_baton)

Answer (score 0):

Not a mace, a club. It's a similar thing, it inflicts  blunt force trauma rather than cutting or burning damage.   And it's not a canon source. But for what it's worth, the police in Futurama use lightsaber clubs.